# Append columns in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Currently, I am using Tableau Desktop and when I add two fields in the column section, it automatically gets nested. But I don't want those two fields to be nested rather it should be appended.
For example, I have two columns named Type of Restaurant and Restaurant brand
Type of restaurant contains the total population and I want that to be in the separate column but type and brand are getting nested

Comment: Are these two columns part of a hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Tableau Community. Replies are faster. Still, just go to the bubble on top and change the data type.

Answer (score 0):

Are the both columns are measures? if yes, you can create new calculated field and add both the columns. If columns are Dimensions then create new calculated field and take count of both columns and add.